# What is the data type STR in winapi?

Tags: winapi

I'm reading a [windows programming book](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/Windows_Programming.pdf) and this is written at 18p.

> STR data types are string data types, with storage already allocated. This data type is
> less common than the LPSTR. STR data types are used when the string is supposed to be
> treated as an immediate array, and not as a simple character pointer.

> LPSTR stands for "Long Pointer to a STR", and is essentially defined as such: #define STR * LPSTR;

(I think second citation has a typo, the author might intend `typedef STR * LPSTR;` by `#define STR * LPSTR;`.)

There is no explanation about what is the `STR` and how it is defined. [This msdn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) also doesn't have a definition of it. And definition of the `LPSTR` is different from the book: `typedef CHAR *LPSTR;`

I think the book says `STR` is an array of character, and I think microsoft says `STR` is the same as CHAR which is defined by `typedef char CHAR;` How should I think about it?

Comment: There is no such thing as `STR` in the Windows header files.

Comment: @RaymondChen Then does `typedef STR * LPSTR;` have nothing to do with Win32? Is it just wrong?

Comment: @opol "*microsoft says `STR` is the same as `CHAR`*" No, they never said that anywhere.

Comment: The line `typedef STR * LPSTR;` appears nowhere in any Windows header files. The definition of `LPSTR` is in `ntdef.h`: `typedef _Null_terminated_ CHAR *NPSTR, *LPSTR, *PSTR;`

Comment: @dxiv It was just my thought because if `typedef STR * LPSTR;` is the same as `typedef CHAR *LPSTR;`, `STR` and `CHAR` should be the same. But it seems that the definition of `LPSTR` in the book is wrong. You should be right. I edited that part.

Comment: @opol In the context this is quoted from, I believe the whole `STR` digression is used to "*justify*" the `sz` prefix for `char[]` strings in Hungarian notation e.g. `char szText[20];`. But that's an artifact of the book, which I find more confusing than helpful. There is no `STR` type defined in the Win32 API, and there is no useful way to define a `STR` type for `char` arrays.